# Weird issue deploying EAR in Weblogic 11g

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, oracle11g

I have this fairly typical EAR project, with library and EJB dependencies; no compilation errors in Eclipse and the project can be published successfully on the Oracle Weblogic server. But when I access the application locally, it gives "NoSuchMethodError" exception at the first call to a method in a superclass. The method itself is not important since I proved that, if I comment out the first error, it breaks at the first subsequent call to a method in a superclass.

But, if I export the main project to EAR and deploy it via the local Weblogic Console, **it works fine and gives no exception whatsoever.** So, the problem is local to Eclipse (or, more precisely, the OEPE).

Weblogic is version 11gR1 (10.3.5). Eclipse is the OEPE which came along with the server, version 3.2.7.
All source files for my projects and the domain directory are the same of my peers, who needless to say have no problem.

This is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
    at hse.core.struts.action.ActionBase.beaInvoke(ActionBase.java)
    at hse.medl.web.actions.PreHome.beaInvokeSuper(PreHome.java)
    at hse.medl.web.actions.PreHome$beaVersion0_584.execute(PreHome.java:29)
    at hse.medl.web.actions.PreHome.execute(PreHome.java)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
    ....
```

Any help, as always, is appreciated.

Comment: This looks a lot like you're using different versions of the jar providing either `PreHome` or `ActionBase`.

Comment: I thought so, but can't find evidence. The problem is not exclusive to PreHome: _any_ Action that calls a superclass gives the exception. I'm trying to find if the superclass is always the same, or not.

Comment: Even _more_ weird (thanks for sp.) is that, sometimes, it works. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out at least the cause: the error is due to the JRebel plugin. I still don't know why or how, but disabling the JRebel solves the issue.

EDIT: The folks at JRebel forum pointed me to a solution. Here it is: http://zeroturnaround.com/forums/topic/cant-run-app-in-weblogic-11gr1-w-jrebel-support/#post-36727